# Is there a way to pause Application Insights alerts (maintenance mode)

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a few Application Insights monitors in place with alerting.  Is there a way to pause these alerts, to define a maintenance window when the site will not be available?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable alerts manually through the Azure Portal.

Just go to your AI application and select the "Alerts" tile. From the alert list select the alert you want to configure, and in the "edit rule" blade, you should see big Enable/Disable buttons.

As far as I know you cannot define a maintenance window that does this automatically.

Comment: This is what I have discovered to date as well.  Thank you for your response